# Cannot install Apache. Missing Dependencies that will not install

Tags: apache2, php, mysql

I am trying to install LAMP on my new server. The problem is that I keep getting a error. Here is what it is:

```
root@178658:~# apt-get install lamp-server^
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.5' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.5' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.5' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2-mpm-prefork' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libapache2-mod-php5' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php5-mysql' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php5-common' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php5-readline' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-5.5' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-common' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'php5-cli' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libmysqlclient18' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2-data' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'apache2-bin' for task 'lamp-server'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2-bin : Depends: libapr1 (>= 1.5.0) but it is not installable
               Depends: libaprutil1 (>= 1.5.0) but it is not installable
               Depends: libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 but it is not installable or
                        libaprutil1-dbd-mysql but it is not installable or
                        libaprutil1-dbd-odbc but it is not installable or
                        libaprutil1-dbd-pgsql but it is not installable or
                        libaprutil1-dbd-freetds but it is not installable
               Depends: libaprutil1-ldap but it is not installable
 mysql-client-5.5 : Depends: libdbd-mysql-perl (>= 1.2202) but it is not installable
                    Depends: libdbi-perl but it is not installable
                    Depends: libterm-readkey-perl but it is not installable
 mysql-server-5.5 : Depends: libdbi-perl but it is not installable
                    Recommends: libhtml-template-perl but it is not installable
 mysql-server-core-5.5 : Depends: libaio1 (>= 0.3.93) but it is not installable
 php5-common : Depends: php5-json but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.'
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this. I already attempted to grep to find broken packages, however, it does not show anything. This is a completely stock install.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: 14.04 LTS for the version.

Comment: What happens when you try to install  libapr1  `sudo apt-get install libapr1`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing them seperately?
Like this:
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 php5-mysql mysql-server
and then also
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
sudo apt-get update

Comment: Did not do the trick. Still got the error.

Answer (score 0):

it might be your `sources.list` file.

run this command in terminal, this will delete `sources.list`

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then run this command:

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

select all the boxes like so:

[image]

Then click on close. Then this window will pop up click on reload.

[image]

Then try to install `lamp-server`

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```